# Why probability distribution is called "a distribution"?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let
there be a $\text{probability space}$ $(\Omega , 2^\Omega , \mathbb{P})$, where
$\mathbb{P}$ is mapping $\mathbb{P}: 2^\Omega \mapsto [0,1]$ , that is, $\mathbb{P}$ is called a probability **measure** (sometimes "a set function", but never "a distribution") on $2^\Omega$. And $X$ is a random variable $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$.

Now, the **distribution** of the random variable $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is the unique probability measure $P$ on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ defined by $$P(B):=\mathbb{P}(X\in B)$$ for every $B$ in $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$, where $[X\in B]=X^{-1}(B)=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)\in B\}$.

*So, the question is:*

Why call $P$ a probability **distribution**? Is there some logic behind the choice of this technical term for $P$? All I see is another function $P$, existence of which was induced by existence of $\mathbb{P}$ and $X$. Well, yes there is, probably, a need to distinguish between measure $\mathbb{P}$ and measure $P$, but to make up new term (distribution), for the sole purpose of differentiating them in talk, is too much.

Comment: It tells you how much weight is placed on a given set. In general, it tells you how the weight is distributed.

Comment: Sorry, but why the same can't be said about the $\mathbb{P}$? I just don't see the "weight" thing. Can you elaborate on the subject. thanks.

Comment: If you repeatedly run an experiment with your random variable $X$, then $P$ models the *distribution* of results (i.e. predicts how much of each result we should expect). That's what I think they're getting at

Comment: If I run experiment without the notion $X$, that is not trying to link objects of  of the space $\Omega$ with numbers $\mathbb{R}$, then $\mathbb{P}$ too can show the distribution of the results. Can it?

Comment: I guess in principle, yes, but  firstly, it has nothing to do with $X$, and secondly, as far as I know, in probability theory you usually do not really care about the space $\Omega$ itself beyond the fact that it exists, so $\Bbb P$ itself is of little interest. It's a mostly auxiliary object.

Comment: But the point is that "random variables" are *made* for modeling such experiments.  A probability measure, in and of itself, doesn't suggest this as strongly.

Comment: Ok, If $\Omega$ is an auxilary thing and $\mathbb{P}$ too, then why not call $P$ measure, since absence of $\mathbb{P}$ frees the term "measure" for another use?

Comment: @coobit I think you have the chronology backwards, at least in some sense.  The idea of distribution functions to describe a statistical law existed decades before Komolgorov's recasting of probability theory in terms of measure spaces in 1933.

Comment: Well, $P$ is a specific measure induced by random variable $X$. You could call it "a pushforward measure induced by $X$" or "a distribution of $X$". It is just a name.

Comment: @coobit I think the point is that the word "distribution" characterizes the relationship between the measure and the random variable in question.  Any probability measure *can* be the distribution of *some* random variable, but if we're not considering a random variable, then we're not thinking about the "distribution" of anything.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, "Any probability measure can be the distribution of some random variable..." My head hurts. Can you make into a full answer?

Comment: @Erick Wong, ok if the $P$ existed long before "measure theory" and before any use of "measure", then why not call $P$ a "probability" or "probability function" or anthing else? Then after measure was "invented" why not call $\mathbb{P}$ a distribution on $\Omega$?

Comment: @coobit Classically, $P$ existed in the form of the cumulative distribution $F(t) = \mathbb P(X < t)$.  It certainly makes sense to call this a distribution rather than a measure, and indeed it makes sense without having the concept of measure.  Once you have such a distribution then countable additivity extends this to a measure on Borel sets, perhaps it is natural to name this extension a distribution also.  To your question why not call $\mathbb P$ a distribution: what variable is it the distribution of??